# How to parse netsh output using python

Tags: python, subprocess, netsh

I'm getting output as expected using:

> import subprocess x = subprocess.call('netsh interface show
>   interface')

as

```
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Ethernet0
```

But when trying to parse netsh output as below:

> x.split()
>   Throws error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'"  I tired several other ways but didn't worked.

I am trying to retrieve(filter) just Interface name from netsh output using python.

Comment: I got the idea and answered but your input code is badly formatted and contains a trailing `as`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.call` just returns the return code, not the output stream of the command.

To do what you want, you could do this instead:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('netsh interface show interface',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
[x,err] = p.communicate()
```

then `x` contains the output provided by the `netsh` program.

As a general remark, note that it's better to pass the arguments in a string like this:

```
['netsh','interface','show','interface']
```

so you have better control of arguments, and can pass arguments with spaces in it without bothering to quote them, quoting is done by `subprocess` module.

Comment: Filtiring results as  x.split() splits each string so if a network name is having more than one word it will split in two string as for example "local" "Network". Anyway convert string data in dataset so that I can retrieve entire network name in one string as "Local Network"?